# How to find the maximum number of words and characters in sentences from a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm loading user's input file that contains sentences into a data frame to display the maximum length of a sentence in characters and in words, but my code returns the lengths of each sentence in the dataframe. I just want the maximum values to be displayed. Any ideas where is my mistake?

```
res = wdata['sentences'].str.split().str.len()
print ("The maximum length in words are : " +  str(res)) 
length = wdata['sentences'].str.len().sort_values()
print ("The maximum length in chars are : " +  str(length)) 

#I expect the output to be 
#The maximum length in words are : 4
#The maximum length in words are : 40
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `max` for get maximum values of lengths:

```
res = wdata['sentences'].str.split().str.len().max()

print("The maximum length in words are : " +  str(res)) 

#solution with f-strings
print(f"The maximum length in words are : {res}")
```

---

```
length = wdata['sentences'].str.len().max()

print("The maximum length in chars are : " +  str(length)) 

#solution with f-strings
print("fThe maximum length in chars are : {length}")
```

Comment: thanks man its working didnt think that its that simple will accept your answer in 10 minutes

Comment: Generally you prefer your print syntax rather than `print("The maximum length in words are :", res)` (multi-param) ?

Comment: @azro - thank you for suggestion,  Iadd `f-string`s solutions.

Comment: Haha I didn't talk about f-string, just pass `res` as a 2nd param :D

Comment: Like `print("fThe maximum length in chars are : {length} and the maximum length in chars are : {length}") ` ?